# Android 2.3 keypad issue with japanese text

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery-mobile, android-emulator, jsp-tags

I have a jQuery Mobile application with first name and last name as textfield on a jsp page.
User need to enters the text in japanese character. But when the user enters the japanese text in first field and places the curson on next field, the keypad language changes from japanese to english. Also the keypad gets locked .

This is the issue coming in Android 2.3.3 emulator.

Any help

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more issue here.
A simple jqueryMobile page with some fields has problem with japanese keypad enabled on emulator.
The problem is when user selects Japanese text on keypad it changes to default keypad when user clicks on last textfield.